# What the difference between struts2 and spring

Tags: spring-mvc, struts2

i am very new to this can any1 tell me the difference between them

Comment: Do you mean Spring MVC? Since spring is a whole set of technologies, while struts 2 is a frontend technology.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is an application framework, it comprises several modules like:

1. Inversion of Control container
2. Aspect-oriented programming JDBC
3. Data access
4. Transaction management
5. Model-view-controller
6. Remote Access framework
7. Batch processing
8. Authentication and authorization
9. Remote Management
10. Testing

...

Struts2 is a web application framework (more specifically  it's an action-oriented framework) based on MVC idea (so it provides one of the spring module task) .